# Excel - one basic formula gives different outputs in different workbooks

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

I'd used the following formula in a test data workbook to pull back the max date associated with a value and it works perfectly:

=MAX(IF(A:A=AE3,U:U))

This is searching column A for the value contained in Cell AE3, and returning the highest associated value in Column U. Works perfectly in my test data, but returns 0 in my live data.

I'd even tried a far simpler formula which still gives a different output between my workbooks; returning TRUE in my test data, and returning FALSE in my live data:

=IF(A:A=AE3,"TRUE")

Clearly the problem is with the A:A=AE3 part, which one workbook seems to be fine with and the other does not like at all, but I can't see why they would behave differently.

Additional info:
the data in both worksheets is in General format, with the exception of the date column referenced in the first formula (column U)
I have used Ctrl + Shift + Enter when using the Max(IF) formula
Both worksheets are xlsx

Any guidance would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Why are you not using `MAXIFS()`? Also, what do you mean with different workbooks? Different versions of Excel? Newest versions of Excel don't require you to CSE nomore while other older versions do.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response - I'm unfortunately using Excel 2013, and I believe MAXIFS() is only available from Excel 2017 onwards. By different workbooks, I just mean two different files. Same version of excel on both

Comment: Then it's hard to say without test-data. It kind of looks to me that none of the values in column A:A actually is exactly the same as the value in AE3. There could be trailing/leading spaces or invisible characters? Or, are you not using CSE? Hard to tell without the data.

Comment: I'd literally copied and pasted the value from Column A into Cell AE and excel still isn't able to find it (in the live workbook). Interestingly when I use the Evaluate Formula feature, I can see that it does find the value in Column A and returns "TRUE" for those values, but the overall value shown in the cell at the end is False. Unfortunately I can't share the data as it's sensitive

Comment: Then there is little to be done from our end.

Comment: Any circular references anywhere?

Comment: No circular references - each column is independent

Comment: Amazingly, if I copy the live data into the test workbook and use the exact same formula, it works... Looks like I have my workaround, though still entirely baffled as to why the same formula wouldn't work by default in the live workbook... Thanks for your responses in any case